# How user can login to custom group in phpfox

Tags: php, phpfox

I am new to php fox , i have a problem in user group module, i understand how to create user group module and the settings of that group but my problem is i am not able to go to the custom user group, always it is going to registered user . please help me and also help me to add custom user group model in registration process.

Comment: When you create an account phpfox will always make it a Registered user group. You can write a plug in that changes this though but you need to know how to program.

Answer (score 0):

You can change user group of any user from admin panel .

`admincp>>users>>Browse Users>>(click on the down arrow appering in the users list)>>edit user`

For user groups on registration you have to create subscriptions. `admincp>>modules>>subscribe>>create new package`.

If you are trying to implement the user group with the select option or a default user group for all the registered users than please change the default registered user group according to your need and create a separate user group for special users.